# draw line with Equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mask, equation

this code make circle with radius r. Is it possible By changing the circle equation to the line equation create a line With specific angles and lengths? if this is feasible, What should be the equation? 
please guide.

```
clc;clear;
mask = zeros(400,600);
position = [200,300];
r = 50;
cx = position(1);
cy = position(2);
[ix,iy] = size(mask);
[x,y]= meshgrid(-(cx-1):(ix-cx),-(cy-1):(iy-cy));
circlemask =((x.^2+y.^2)<=r^2)';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may follow like below:

First refer this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-points-at-a-given-distance-on-a-line-of-given-slope/) to understand how to get one end of the straight line given slope and one end of the line.

Second, the code needs to find some intersection points, for which I have used a MATLAB file exchange function InterX from this [link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22441-curve-intersections?focused=5165138&tab=function).

Check the code below:

```
mask = zeros(400,600);
% mesh grid for the zone 
[X,Y]= meshgrid(1:600,1:400) ;
L1 = [X(:) Y(:)] ;
% Given line details 
A = [200,300];   % one end of line 
th = 45 ;    % slope of line in degrees 
m = tand(th) ; % slope of the line 
d = 100 ;    % Length of the line we want 
% get the other end of line 
x = [A(1)+ d*sqrt(1/(1+m^2)) A(1)- d*sqrt(1/(1+m^2))] ;
y = [A(2)+ m*d*sqrt(1/(1+m^2)) A(2)- m*d*sqrt(1/(1+m^2))] ;
B =  [x(1) y(1)] ;
% Get nearest neighbors of points of the line in mask 
idx1 = knnsearch(L1,A) ;
idx2 = knnsearch(L1,B) ;
% Get intersection points 
L2 = [[A(1) x(1)]' [A(2) y(1)]']' ;  % take A and B points 
P = InterX(L1',L2) ;
idx = knnsearch(L1,P') ;
mask(idx) = 1 ;
imshow(mask)
```

The output of the code looks like below:

[image]

Comment: i write this loop for increase thickness of the line: `for i=1:10
    mask(idx+i) = 1;
    mask(idx-i) = 1;
end` but the output is dentate.